# What data do I need to build a map?

Tags: carto

I am brand new to mapping. I work in a hospital and I'd like to plot 55 sites of pedestrian and bike accidents onto a map of brooklyn (so we can see patterns and consider interventions). Most of my data is intersections, not addresses, plus zip.

How can I turn this into a map?

The data comes from our trauma registry, it is not public. it is in an excel sheet. i don't know what shapefiles or tabular means! it's just street addresses and interactions.

I'd like to make an online map. I got to this site from Carto and didn't realize it was separate.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Lizzie. Could you please describe your data a bit more? What type of data do you have (shapefiles, tabular, etc)? Is it a public source?

Comment: What kind of map? A paper map? An offline digital map? A web map?

Comment: Hi Aaron, the data comes from our trauma registry, it is not public. it is in an excel sheet. i don't know what shapefiles or tabular means! it's just street addresses and interactions.

Comment: Thanks James, I'd like to make an online map. Sorry, I got to this site form Carto and didn't realize it was separate.

Comment: Lizzie, welcome to the geospatial world. As the data is not public is it allowed to become public? Creating a webmap usually means making the data public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of options, all of which assume that you will be okay with this online map being publicly available.  If this is not the case please mention that.

1. You could identify an address for each intersection location and then use something like https://batchgeo.com/ to create a map for you.
2. Alternatively, you could manually create the map yourself using something like http://mapmaker.nationalgeographic.org/.

Both of these options are free, but have limits on the amount of data they'll let you map.